# Docker Pull/Import from File System

Tags: docker, artifactory

We have server where all the docker images are pushed like this it's artifactory and pushed like files.

How to pull or import this to docker images for local playground. Any idea? or the sharing method is wrong.

```
Index of docker-tech/
Name                   Last modified      Size
centos7-base/           01-Mar-2019 07:48    -
jdk8/                   01-Mar-2019 07:48    -
jre8/                   01-Mar-2019 07:49    -
maven/                  01-Mar-2019 07:50    -
nginx/                  02-Jan-2019 03:15    -
node/                   02-Jan-2019 03:15    -
swaggerapi_swagger-ui/  02-Jan-2019 03:14    -
tomcat/                 01-Mar-2019 07:50    -
wallet-gateway-api/     02-Jan-2019 03:20    -
wallet-gateway-doc/     03-Jan-2019 07:21    -
```

Comment: How did you get the images there initially?  What's in those directories?

Comment: There are manifest.json and some sha files. Some has pushed it to this folder i believe. I will check with relevant team

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze I got tot know how to pull from Artifactory, it will be folder.<URL>/image name : tag

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using artifactory you can use the docker save command this will save your images in a tar archive -- which you can push to a server along with versioning.

```
docker save --output <image_name>.tar <image_name>
```